# How to index symbols in Rails projects with Ctags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I am using `vim-scripts/ctags.vim` and everything is pretty sweet except symbols. Example:

```
# spec/message_spec.rb
context :message_set do
  include_context :message_set
end

# spec/support/contexts/message_set.rb
RSpec.shared_context :message_set do
  # ...
end
```

But no matter what I do, I can't jump to `:message_set` definition in the file named `message_set.rb` from the `message_spec.rb` via `gf` or `Ctrl-]`. Of course I can use a fuzzy finder, but that is like doing Ctags job manually.

How to tell Ctags to index symbols in Ruby?

Comment: 1. you don't need that plugin to interact with ctags and 2. you must index your code before doing a tag search. Read `:help tags` and `:help ctags`.

Comment: I am indexing my code and can jump to method definitions both inside my project and gems. The only thing that's missing - symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You can add symbols support to ctags with this line in `~/.ctags`:

```
--regex-ruby=/(:["']*[A-Za-z_]*["']*)/\1/s,symbol,symbols/
```

Pressing `gf` should work with Vim's default Ruby support files (well it does here).